# How to import preloadallmodules?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

```
import { Routes, RouterModule, PreloadAllModules } from '@angular/router';
```

I get this error

@angular/router/index"' has no exported member 'PreloadAllModules'.

Do I need to update angular2 so it has PreloadAllModules or is it something else I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [changelog](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#210-beta0-2016-09-23) it was first added in 2.1.0-beta.0, so every very after that should have it.

Angular is currently at version 2.2.4, I'm not sure what Angular version you are currently on, but I'd advise you to keep your version as close to the latest release as possible.
There haven't been a lot of breaking changes since 2.0.0 final, so upgrading just not take that much time.

Comment: Ahh that was it I'm on 2.0.0